# TFS Query to get blank (or) no entries in Acceptance Criteria field of Feature or User Story

Tags: tfs, acceptance

I want to write a TFS Query to get blank (or) no entries in Acceptance Criteria field/box for Features or User Story's in project.

How can I write Query as I can't see any = or <> operators against 'Acceptance Criteria'. Only I can see 'Contains Words' & 'Does Not Contains Words', from these how can we get blank entries?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Starting with Azure DevOps 2019 Server (TFS 2019) there is a new operator for HTML fields "IsEmpty" that does what you want to do.  Prior to that version you cannot do this in a query.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=azure-devops#query-operators

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this search.
you can make a full search then export the results to excel then filter there :(

Comment: Thank you for response. so there is no other way to find if Acceptance Criteria (or) Description fields are empty for Features or User story's without extracting data into excel & filtering.

Comment: maybe you can try using the api